# Optimization problem - algebraic solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to automatize some processes just using excel and I have found one which is eluding my capacity of finding a proper algebraic solution for it. It goes like this:

Let     $a_1*b_1+a_2*b_2+a_3*b_3+...a_n*b_n=x$
where  ***n***  goes from 5 to 15.

I need to find only the five ***a*** * ***b*** pairs which added together equate the maximum value for ***x***?

**a**s and **b**s are given.

I'm struggling to formulate the situation correctly, please bear with me  as english is not my first language and I think that in my first one I'm also strugling to define it!

Thanks in advance for any help and for your time.

Regards,

Carlos.

Comment: do you need to select exactly $n$ pairs, or do you need to select from $n$ pairs a subset which produces the maximum?

Comment: Are the $a$s and $b$s given?

Comment: I just need to select a subset from ***n*** pairs, ussualy 5.

Comment: Yes, ***a***s and ***b***s are given.

Comment: I'm I wrong thinking this is a lineal algebra problem?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your data are given in pairs seems irrelevant. You could just as soon set $c_i = a_i*b_i$ for all $i$. Then the problem is to select the $k$ largest of these. Excel has a function to help you with this, LARGE(array,i). I do not know how efficient this method is, and if $n$ and $k$ vary, then you may have to use some reference functions to express the arrays properly.

Another option is to use VBA programming.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a look.